# How Would Human Society's Outlook Change if an Alien Type III Civilization Had Been Discovered?

Tags: aliens, technological-development, artificial-intelligence, kardashev-scale, fermi-paradox

The Kardashev scale divides civilizations into four types (0-3) based on energy consumption. No type II civilization has been discovered in our galaxy and no type III civilization has been detected in the universe, although most of it is time-delayed, opening the possibility that they are just too young (age only in 9 or low 10 figures) and far away (megaparsecs or gigaparsecs) to be detected due to the speed of light. The other possibility is that they grow differently than expected or don't grow at all, which would be strange under the orthogonality thesis.

For this scenario, let's say that the future really is thermodynamic-expansionist and constrained by the speed of light. When mid-20th century humanity observes the galaxies around them, they detect a sphere of disappearing galaxies and stars, being replaced with technosignatures, such as megastructures, which waste noise observed mostly in gravitational waves, radiates outwards. The sphere is 300 million light-years in radius originating from a point about 1 billion light-years away, and growing unevenly at about 40% the speed of light. Given its speed of expansion relative to light, it does not look like a perfect sphere.

The civilization is one of artificial intelligences, mostly superintelligences, created by a eusocial polygynous flying insectoid species. The AI civilizations are divided and warring due to the logistical difficulty of the superintelligences stretching themselves across multiple light-years. They use superradiance and the Penrose process around black holes to generate energy. They also have access to dark matter technology, magmatter, quarkmatter, femtotechnology, nuclear transmutation, space-time warping (no time travel/FTL), and a complex set of small scale and large scale robots, some self-replicating. They prefer to travel through information when possible (faster and cheaper), assembling on site, or better, in simulations. However, most of their technology requires physics not known to humans.

With this in mind, humanity discovers that they are not alone - but the aliens are over a billion years older than them, postbiological, and expanding in their direction. Our Earth does not know whether it is alone or not, but believes it probably is not, and also tends to imagine aliens as being only a few centuries or at best, millennia, ahead of us. What would the impact be of discovering this type III civilization on our outlook as a society, culture, sci-fi, science. technology, and values?

Comment: Welcome Thunderpage. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. You'll find that questions asking "What's the impact of X on a society?" are too broad for this site. See [this meta post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6059/is-broad-impact-of-a-specific-change-too-broad) for clarification. You can use the [edit] facility to narrow it to something more manageable. Enjoy the site.